# How to add new key-value to dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
contacts = {'John Smith': '1-123-123-123',
            'Jane Smith': '1-102-555-5678',
            'John Doe': '1-103-555-9012'}


def add_contact(contacts, name, number):
    """
    Add a new contact (name, number) to the contacts list.
    """
    if name in contacts:
        print(name, "is already in contacts list!")
    else:
        contacts[name] = number

print(add_contact(contacts, 'new_guy', '1234'))
```

When I print this I get `none`

but if I add another line `print(contacts)`

it will give me a `none` and the new dictionary with `'new_guy' :'1234'.` What is the correct way to print out the new dictionary without printing `none`?

Comment: You're adding to the dictionary correctly. You are printing wrong. Your print statement prints the result of the function. Your function doesn't return anything.

Comment: Right. Since your function modifies in place, don't print it.  Just call `add_contact(contacts, 'new_guy', '1234')`, then `print(contacts)`.

Comment: It would work as written if you just add `return contacts` at the end of your `add_contact` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding to the dictionary correctly. Yor print statement is the issue.

Change this:

`print(add_contact(contacts, 'new_guy', '1234'))`

You need to separate this out some.

```
add_contact(contacts, 'new_guy', '1234')
print(contacts)
```

Also, since your `contacts` dictionary is declared globally, you <strike>don't need to pass it to the function</strike> should name it something different in the function for clarity. You could change the function to:

```
def add_contact(current_contacts, name, number):
```

But don't for get to change inside the function as well.

```
if name in current_contacts:
        print(name, "is already in contacts list!")
    else:
        current_contacts[name] = number
```

**The final code:**

```
contacts = {'John Smith': '1-123-123-123',
            'Jane Smith': '1-102-555-5678',
            'John Doe': '1-103-555-9012'}


def add_contact(current_contacts, name, number):
    """
    Add a new contact (name, number) to the contacts list.
    """
    if name in current_contacts:
        print(name, "is already in contacts list!")
    else:
        current_contacts[name] = number


add_contact(contacts, 'new_guy', '1234')
print(contacts)
```

Comment: Telling him to rely on the global is bad advice.  I would remove that suggestion.  Globals are evil.

Comment: OP's `add_contact` will work with any contact dictionary. Its just coincidental that it has the same name as the global. Moving to use the global instead reduces functionality. It doesn't make any difference for the example posted, but should be noted in your comment.

Comment: @tdelaney That's true, I just didn't think about it given that it is using the same name, which is exactly why it shouldn't be the same name. I'll edit it to change it.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it right now, you are printing what the function returns (which is none). All you need to do is separate your functional call and print statement like so:

```
    add_contact(contacts, 'new_guy', '1234')
    print(contacts)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def add_contact(name, number):
    """
    Add a new contact (name, number) to the contacts list.
    """
    if name in contacts:
        print(name, "is already in contacts list!")
    else:
        contacts[name] = number
    return contacts #put a return statement that will return the updated contacts dictionary

print(add_contact('John Doe', '1234'))


#for simplified version try a dictionary comprehension:
#using the dict.update(), we can use a comprehension inside to iterate from the contacts itself and have a condition if the name is already exists
contacts.update({key: value for key, value in contacts.items() if key not in contacts})

#tho, we can't have a print statement that will tell if the name already exist in the contacts
print(contacts)

>>>output: {'John Smith': '1-123-123-123', 'Jane Smith': '1-102-555-5678', 'John Doe': '1-103-555-9012'}
```